# The property 'Dish_ID' cannot be used as a key property on the entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to add some entities using EntityFramework. 
I need the same model as in image
[image: I need the same model as in image]
I created two classes:

```
public class PriceOfDish
{
    [Key]
    public virtual List<Dish> Dish_ID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
public class Dish
{
    [Key]
    public int Dish_ID { get; set; }
    public string DishName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual FoodCategory FoodCategory_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Feature Feature_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderedDishes> Orders { get; set; }

}
```

Using FluentAPI trying to set primary keys:

```
 builder.Entity<PriceOfDish>()
            .HasKey(t => new {t.Dish_ID, t.DateTime});
```

During updating DB i get error message: "The property 'Dish_ID' cannot be used as a key property on the entity 'testFOef.PriceOfDish' because the property type is not a valid key type. Only scalar types, string and byte[] are supported key types.". 
But why? Can you explain this to me? Thanks for any help

Comment: notice that the error mentions about the `PriceOfDish` class, not the `Dish` class. You can't simply use List<Dish> as an id. You have to look for `Composite Key` for the scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the error say you are using a `List<Dish>` as a type for your primary key. You must use an scalar type (value type) as usual or byte[].

For you, the solution is to create a proprerty `Dish_ID` with `int` type.

```
public class PriceOfDish
{
    [Key]
    public int Dish_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Dish_Id")]
    public virtual Dish Dish { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: but how EF will find this property from "Dish" table?

Comment: It will find it by convention. It will look for a proprerty with name DishId or Dish_ID.

Comment: This really works but entity created with keys and without connection with "Dish" table. I'm so sorry about this simple question and my bad english

Comment: I edited my code and added an attribute to the Dishes collection which tell EF which property to use as a foreign key.

Comment: Some errors, you can not use an collection in this class because we have one Dish_Id which belong to on Dish class instance.

Answer (score 2):

you're trying to set a `List<Dish> Dish_ID` as a key of a table.
But this is not supported. It doesn't make much sense either. list of `Dish`es that will have a single `Price`? I think you want to put `int Dish_ID` there